# TFS asking for Check Out when the solution is build or solution is opened?

Tags: c#, tfs

When Source Control settings in Tools -> options is changed for "Prompt when Check out".Then it ask for check out else it would automatically check out.

This check out should not happen when nothing is modified.

Let me know what might be the problem how to do settings to avoid this problem in TFS Source Control.

Comment: You may have some of the build outputs checked into TFS - not sure why it would prompt for a checkout when the solution is opened though.

Comment: @RB. Sorry its not the solution that is getting checkout but its the project in the solution that is getting checked out.

Comment: Have you compared and seen what actually is changing in the project?

Comment: @TheShooter I compared but nothing has been changed but the project(csproj) in the solution is getting checked out.

Comment: Did you run the compare after saving everything or before that?

Comment: @TheShooter I compared after saving

Comment: @TheShooter Compared files is showing difference in Project reference since it was renamed .How to change that and check in

Comment: @TheShooter The Problem is solved.Thanks for the response.

Comment: This was happening since the auto generated csproj file had wrong reference checked into tfs.Hence It forcefully resolving itself by checking out the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced similar situation in case the CSPROJ has some invalid setting, for example the Guid of the project is the same as the Guid of another project in the same solution.  Such things can happen when copying and modifying CSPROJs by hand.

My suggestion: after opening Studio modifies the CSPROJ, check the change in the Pending Changes, and decide if they are correct/acceptable or not.  If yes, check it in, and problem solved.

Comment: I was thinking the same to check-in things. Yes the problem here is also with csproj and it was being renamed and then this problem has  ocurred.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck this:

```
Tools->Options->Source Control->Environment
       Checked-in items
              Saving: Check out automatically
```

It should work.

Comment: I don't want to it to be checked out at all. So no point in setting that option.

Comment: It's unchecked.

Comment: but anyway it ask for check out. solution build only when check out else it will not build